# How to generate token for google service account

Tags: access-token, google-oauth, service-accounts

```
from google.oauth2 import service_account
credentials = service_account.Credentials.from_service_account_file(
    'service-account.json')
print(credentials.__dict__)
```

That print statement prints credentials but in that token is printed as none and expiry is also printed as none.
JSON file

```
{  
"type": "service_account"    
"project_id": xxxxxxxxxx     
"private_key_id": xxxxxxxxxx   
"private_key": xxxxxxxxxx   
"client_email": xxxxxxxxxx   
"client_id": xxxxxxxxxx   
"auth_uri": xxxxxxxxxx   
"token_uri": xxxxxxxxxx  
"auth_provider_x509_cert_url": xxxxxxxxxx  
"client_x509_cert_url": xxxxxxxxxx  
}
```

Please help me how to generate token for service account with expiry time.

Comment: [Edit] to include the language "tag".

Comment: @Mahesh Maddineni can you share more about the environment you're trying to generate the JWT in?